# Generalized weight space

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

In their  [paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1976-216-00/S0002-9947-1976-0404361-X/) Lepowsky and Mcmollum sketch theory of weights in a more general setting. Here is their definition of a weight space:

If $A$ is a subset of $\mathfrak g$ and $\lambda$ is a function from $A$ into $k$, $V^{\lambda}_A$ is the set of $x\in\mathfrak g$ such that some power of $\pi(a)-\lambda(a)$ annihilates $x$ for all $a\in A$. The function $\lambda$ such that  $A$ into $k$, $V^{\lambda}_A \neq 0$ is called aweight vector.

here $\mathfrak g$ is a lie algebra over a field $k$ and $\pi: \mathfrak g \rightarrow End(V) $ a representation of $\mathfrak g$ on a vctor space $V$.

My question : Shouldn't $V^{\lambda}_A $ be the set of $x\in V$ instead of $x\in\mathfrak g$ in the first line?

Comment: Yes. It looks like its just a typo.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be an obvious misprint, probably due to the authors' interest in the adjoint representation.    If in doubt, check with Lepowsky, who is at Rutgers.   [By the way, your own formulation could use some proofreading.]